# Creation of FTP credentials for Wordpress local

Tags: wordpress, ftp, xampp, ftps

I've installed wordpress local on my computer with xampp, it's working but now I need to transfer my wordpress.com on my wordpress local. I want to add an extension but it's asking me my FTP credentials and I'm not finding them nor succeeding in creating some. I've tried the different things I found on your forum (chmod, define FS method) but it's not successfull, when i try to download an extension, it tells me that it can't be added to the file. How can I do it please ?

Thank you :) !

Answer (score 0):

If it's asking you for FTP credentials to transfer it through the web, that won't be possible as your site is not reachable, it's only installed locally. This is doable by adding some extra software to make your site accessible, like ngrok.

Instead of that, why don't you use the site exporter?
https://wordpress.com/support/export/

Additionally, if you have a Business or eCommerce plan, you can use a plugin to export your site, like [enter link description here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)